DAX measure for dynamical calculation of value based on previous date
I have four tables: Daily Inventory, AFPO, RESB, and EKPO.
Daily inventory:



Material ID
Date Added
Total Value




1
08/19/2024
50


2
08/19/2024
100


3
08/19/2024
1000



AFPO and EKPO have almost the same headers and data, they are both incoming materials which will increase inventory value:
EKPO:



Material ID
Delivery Date
Value




1
08/19/2024
50


2
08/20/2024
100


3
08/21/2024
1000


1
08/20/2024
55


3
08/24/2024
500



AFPO:



Material ID
Basic finish date
Value




1
08/19/2024
40


2
08/20/2024
60


3
08/21/2024
300


1
08/20/2024
155


3
08/24/2024
250



RESB is the table with requirements with the same headers as AFPO but the value needs to be subtracted from the Daily Inventory total value.
RESB:



Material ID
Requirements Date
Value




1
08/19/2024
200


2
08/20/2024
300


3
08/21/2024
2000


1
08/20/2024
150


3
08/24/2024
700



I am trying to create a measure within "Date" table (it is connected to AFPO, EKPO, RESB, and Daily Inventory via Date column with other date type columns) which has one column "Date" starting from current day.
Here is the screenshot of the relationships between the tables:
The measure should provide how the "Total Value" from Daily Inventory will change over the next 7 days.
Date:



Date




08/19/2024


08/20/2024


08/21/2024


08/22/2024


08/23/2024


08/24/2024


08/25/2024


08/26/2024


08/27/2024



Here is the measure I have tried which almost provides the desired result:
Inventory Forecast = 
VAR _today = TODAY()
VAR _sum =
    SUM ( 'DailyInventory'[Total Value])
VAR _else =
    SUM ( 'AFPO'[Value] ) + SUM ( 'EKPO'[Value] )
        - SUM ( 'RESB'[Value] )
-- Forecast for today's date
VAR _forecast_today =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'DailyInventory'[Total Value] ),
        'Date'[Date] = _today
    )
-- Forecast for the next 7 days
VAR _forecast_7_days =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'DailyInventory'[Total Value]),
        DATESINPERIOD ( 'Date'[Date], _today, 7, DAY )
    )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE(),
        MAX ( 'Date'[Date] ) = _today, _forecast_today + _else,
        MAX ( 'Date'[Date] ) > _today && MAX ( 'Date'[Date] ) <= _today + 7, _forecast_7_days + _else,
        _sum
    )

The issue with this measure is that for every next day, it takes current day's (08/19/2024) "Daily Inventory" total value rather than taking previous day Total value after EKPO, AFPO, and RESB summation.
While this measure would work for the first day 8/19/2024, for other dates it will not.
For example: For 08/21/2024, it will use 08/19/2024 Total value and subtract the requirements from 8/21/2024 instead of taking value of 08/20/2024 after all the summation.
I would appreciate any help.

Can you share the data for all your tables and how you are linking them together?

@AmiraBedhiafi Added the data for other tables and their relationships.

could you also provide the expected output in the table?

Try this measure:
Inventory Forecasted (final) = 
VAR xDays = 7 //Range
VAR thisDate = MAX('Date'[Date]) 
VAR _today = TODAY()
VAR todayRange =  _today + xDays

VAR currentInv = //Gets today's inventory
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX(ALL('DailyInventory'), [Total Value]),
        DailyInventory[Date Added] = _today 
    )

VAR _AFPO = //sums Value between this date and today ignoring relationships
    CALCULATE (
        SUM(AFPO[Value]),
        AFPO[Basic finish date] <= thisDate && AFPO[Basic finish date] >= _today,
        REMOVEFILTERS()
    )
VAR _EKPO = //sums Value between this date and today ignoring relationships
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'EKPO'[Value]),
        EKPO[Delivery Date] <= thisDate  && EKPO[Delivery Date] >= _today,
        REMOVEFILTERS()
    )
VAR _RESB = //sums Value between this date and today ignoring relationships
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'RESB'[Value]),
        RESB[Requirements Date] <= thisDate  && RESB[Requirements Date] >= _today,
        REMOVEFILTERS()
    )
RETURN IF(thisDate >= todayRange, BLANK(), currentInv + _AFPO + _EKPO - _RESB ) //Return Blank if date outside of range


This measure will sum the DailyInventory[Total Value] for today, then for each following day (over 7 days), the summation (AFPO + EKPO - RESB) will be added to a rolling total.



Date
Inventory for Today
AFPO
EKPO
RESB
(AFPO + EKPO - RESB)
Inventory Forecasted (final)




8/20/2024
1150
340
1050
2200
-810
340


8/21/2024

60
100
300
-140
200


8/22/2024

0
0
0
0
200


8/23/2024

0
0
0
0
200


8/24/2024

155
55
150
60
260


8/25/2024

250
500
700
50
310


8/26/2024

200
20
100
120
430


8/27/2024

400
50
200
250




